# Não estou conseguindo fazer UPDATE na minha tabela

Tags: php

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site de marcação online, e na parte do administrador onde ele controla os horarios da tabela tinha criado um campo que pode fazer alteração na hora da tabela... onde que essa tabela é mostrada para o usuario onde ele ver quais horários estão disponiveis. 
Nesse campo que criei para o administrador poder alterar não esta funcionando, ele não me apresenta nenhum erro, e quando clico no botão para finalizar, lá no banco dados não sofre nenhuma alteração... pode-se perceber que eu pego o id e colocar o horario que ele deseja mudar, pois cada dia da semana tem uma tabela, (tabela de segunda, tabela de terca, tabela de quarta e assim por diante). O meu problema é que ele não sofre nenhuma alteração quando vou dar UPDATE

codigo alterar.php

```
<?php
$idSeg = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-segunda");
$seg = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "seg");

$idTerca = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-ter");
$tercaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "ter");


$idQuarta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-quarta");
$quartaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qua");


$idQuinta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-quinta");
$quintaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qui");

$idSexta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-sexta");
$sextaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "sex");

$idSabado = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-sabado");
$sabadoo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "sab");


include("conexao.php");

if($idSeg && $seg && $idTerca && $tercaa && $idQuarta && $quartaa &&
     $idQuinta && $quintaa && $idSexta && $sextaa && $idSabado && $sabadoo ) {

    if($link) {
    $segg = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_segunda set horas_de_segunda='$seg' where id='$idSeg';");
    $terc = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_terca set horas_de_terca='$tercaa' where id='$idTerca';");
    $quarr = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_quarta set horas_de_quarta='$quartaa' where id='$idQuarta';");
    $quinn = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_quinta set horas_de_quinta='$quintaa' where id='$idQuinta';");
    $sexx = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_sexta set horas_de_sexta='$sextaa' where id='$idSexta';");
    $sabaa = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_sabado set horas_de_sabado='$sabadoo' where id='$idSabado';");

    header("Location: ../Adm/AdmAgenda.php");
 }
    else {
    die("Erro: " .mysqli_error($link));
 }
}

?>
```

codigo html

```
<?php include("../php/agenda.php"); include("../php/alterar.php"); include("../php/HorasDisponivel.php") ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Administração</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/visual.css">
    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="../js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TempoHorasP1">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="block-left">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="nav-logo col-md-8 righ-menu">
                                        <img src="../Imagens/logo-branco.png" alt="Studio 7 Hair">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-4" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="AdmAgenda.php" class="item-menu-adm"><span>Seja bem vindo</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="item-menu-adm"><span>Configuração da Agenda</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="cadastro.html" class="item-menu-adm"><span>Cadastrar Administrador</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.miyomic.com.br" class="item-menu-adm"><span>Solicitar Ajuda</span></a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="dourado texto-centro margin-top30 bold">Configuração da agenda online</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-alterar margin-top40 texto-centro">
            <h3 class="margin-top20 dourado">Área de alteração dos horários</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Segunda feira</p>

                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="segunda">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-segunda" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="seg" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Terça feira</p>

                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="terca">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-ter" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="ter" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Quarta feira</p>

                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="quarta">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-quarta" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="qua" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Quinta feira</p>
                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="quinta">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-quinta" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="qui" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Sexta feira</p>

                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="sexta">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-sexta" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="sex" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora-alte">
                    <p>Sabádo feira</p>

                    <form action="../php/alterar.php" name="sabado">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="id-sabado" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Id" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="sab" class="campo-alteracao" placeholder="Horas" />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="botao-edit">
                            <a class="botao-alterar">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>
                                <input type="submit" class="invisivel" value="Alterar" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Para poder ter sucesso na alteração da agenda terá que ver qual id que deseja para poder selecionar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se alguem conseguir me ajudar fico grato...

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro é de lógica, aqui:

```
if($idSeg && $seg && $idTerca && $tercaa && $idQuarta && $quartaa &&
     $idQuinta && $quintaa && $idSexta && $sextaa && $idSabado && $sabadoo ) {
.
.
```

O trecho **só vai ser executado** se ***todas*** a variáveis forem verdadeiras, verifique melhor a condição que deseja a faça as correções.